Ether Presale json file extracting different ethereum address
I bought Ethereum using three wallets and was able to access two of them, but I can't access the last one. When I opened the third JSON file, I could see the Ether address. I also checked on Etherscan and confirmed that it contains Ethereum. However, when I decrypt that wallet in geth, it gives a different Ether address output. I can access the file with MyEtherWallet too, but I can't find my real account which has the balance in it. I also have the email that was used to buy Ethereum, but I deleted all of the files a long time ago. Can I get my backup file again?

The presale wallets were only stored on your computer. There was no remote backup.
